# What is the downside of using smaller set of UDP ports in TURN server?

Tags: udp, webrtc

According to [RFC5766](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766.html#section-6.2), it seems that TURN server should have UDP port 49152 - 65535 open for relay.

> In all cases, the server SHOULD only allocate ports from the range 49152 - 65535 (the Dynamic and/or Private Port range [Port-Numbers]),

However, some of the TURN servers, such as Coturn, [allow you to specify](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/blob/master/examples/etc/turnserver.conf#L154) even smaller set of UDP ports for relay.

Because Docker consumes substantial amount of CPU/RAM resources when large port mappings need to be created between a container and a host, I am interested in using smaller set of ports to mitigate high resource usage when I am deploying dockerized TURN server.

I want to know the implications of using smaller set of UDP ports, such as from 49500-50000 (Using 500 UDP ports open) vs 49152-65535 (Using ~16400 UDP ports).

What are the downside of using smaller set of ports for relay? If there is no downside, why does TURN recommend using so many UDP ports for relay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use as few ports as you want, it just limits the amount of allocations you can have.

Each TURN Allocation (session) needs a dedicated 3-Tuple (IP/Port/Protocol)

Comment: Does that mean that a single TURN server can only handle at most 16383 connections (Port 49152~65535) concurrently due to port limitations?

Comment: Correct. With coturn you usually hit CPU constraints before that though.

Comment: @SeanDuBois Hi I have a question regarding TURN server firewall rules, does the TURN server need to allow all outbound port traffic in the firewall setting in order to work? If a TURN server has deny all outbound ports besides the popular ports like 443 and 80 is there a way to get around that?