# How user is able to connect with turn server and not directly to webtrc machine?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

I was curious on why a client cannot directly to a machine running webrtc server but can do that via turn server. Both turn & webrtc are in same VPC of AWS.

Comment: there is no such thing as webrtc server. Do you mean peer-to-peer? WebRTC connects one client to another either directly (if NAT allows it), or indirectly (via TURN server)

Comment: Well I meant a machine which is running in AWS is one peer and other peers are my consumers. All consumers connect with AWS machine peer. I am asking why would NAT allow my connection to turn machine and not to aws peer, as both are hosted on AWS and both have public ips

Answer (score 0):

Could be a lot of things.

Assuming you have the TURN configuration file correct, and as you are noting both AWS instances have public IPs, then it's possible that on the instance with the TURN server, you do not have all the firewall ports opened needed related to the TURN server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59212004/8201657

Or, maybe it's a DNS issue and the domain of your TURN server is unknown to your peer, so it is not able to access it.

Or, maybe you are attempting to connect via WebRTC but not securely. WebRTC requires a secure connnection (https).