# Coturn docker on arm32 (Raspberry Pi) is failing due to port-range and TLS problem

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, port, nat, coturn

this is my first question here so hope I do everything correct.

I'm using Docker image 4.5.2-r3 (with 4.5.2-r2 it was the same) on arm32 (RPi4) with Raspbian/Debian Buster. I get quite some errors and all clients (inside and outside the servers network/my home network) are stucked in "connecting".

This is my turnserver.conf

```
use-auth-secret
static-auth-secret={hidden}
realm=turn.{address-hidden}

min-port=49152
max-port=49172
external-ip={hidden}

log-file=stdout
pidfile=/var/tmp/turnserver.pid
userdb=/var/tmp/turnserver.db

no-cli
cert={Path hidden}
pkey={Path hidden}
no-tlsv1
no-tlsv1_1

prod
no-tcp-relay
```

The server is behind a NAT, all ports are open in ufw and forwarded in the router.
If I use credentials and test it with ICE Trickle it is working but when making calls I get this in the logs:
(this is the actual order the errors are occuring, some of them a few times in a row)

`create_relay_ioa_sockets: no available ports 3`
`incoming packet message processed, error 508: Cannot create socket`
`TLS/TCP socket buffer operation error (callback)`
`incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized`
`incoming packet message processed, error 403: Forbidden IP`

Any ideas? I'm stucked with this for days and am (google is) running out of ideas! Thanks in advance...

Edit: I used `mtr` and Trickle ICE and the ports are open and forwarded correctly. Is there maybe another/a better solution to check that?

Comment: have you checked the required ports are available?, depending on the setup  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193091/which-ports-should-be-allowed-in-firewall-to-use-turn-server

Comment: sorry should have mentioned that and edited my post

Comment: my comment was based on 'create_relay_ioa_sockets: no available ports 3' in your error, mayby try max-port= 65535 as per the spec, also incoming is in range 0- 65535. I use sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN | grep XXX not sure if it works on pi, also is the port range specified when you create the container?

Comment: thanks @NigelSavage yeah the port range is specified on creation of container and its so much lower then coturns defaults due to individual iptable rules docker creates (if I got it right). the netstat command is working like that, I also used it before and it showed normal open ports and no conflicts... anyway the issue was solved via github (hurray!!) - see edit!

Comment: Your solution is valuable for people, would be great if you could answer your question perhaps with a few more details so someone new to the stack could get it up and running on the pi

Comment: tried to do as you said...thought it is detailed enough.

Comment: Thanks for your updates, this is really helpful info for setup on pi, I meant as an answer below. No probs.

Comment: ah, makes more sense... changed it. Now it should be alright for sbd. with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Issue was solved via [GitHub](https://github.com/spantaleev/matrix-docker-ansible-deploy/issues/1214#issuecomment-900158835), thanks to pushytoxin!! Solution was to configure the udp portrange for the relay-ports coturn is using to be extended (to 49152-49272 so 100 ports more) and the TLS part due to a [bug](https://github.com/spantaleev/matrix-docker-ansible-deploy/pull/1145) in Element mobile clients regarding "Lets encrypt"-cert-chains...

Step-by-step:

1. in `turnserver.conf` set `min-port=49152` `max-port=49272`. If it still gives the same error try extending the portrange even further
2. open the extended portrange in your firewall and if necessary forward it in your router
3. if your are using lets-encrypt: in your `homeserver.yaml` set the two entries (udp and tcp) under `turn_uris:` to `turn:` instead of `turns:` - see [here](https://github.com/spantaleev/matrix-docker-ansible-deploy/pull/1145)